# Adding group to the Team Folder using API not working

Tags: dropbox-api

I am having issues when trying to add group to a team folder using the Dropbox API v2.
I am trying to add group to team folder using the **2/sharing/add_folder_member** route

I am sending the request with this body:

```
{
  "shared_folder_id": :team_folder_id,
  "members": [
    {
      "member": {
        ".tag": "dropbox_id",
        "dropbox_id": :group_id
      },
      "access_level": {
        ".tag": "editor"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

, and headers:

```
Authorization [Bearer :team_member_file_access_token], 
Dropbox-API-Select-User [:business_account_owner_team_member_id]
```

The provided user in the headers is member of the group. Because adding user to a group is async operation, I am waiting until the job is complete before sending request to add group to a team folder.

This API call was working fine before, but since the last week always gives **access_error - not_a_member** error.

Is there a bug with Dropbox, or is there a new way to preform this action?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Adding-group-to-the-Team-Folder-using-API-not-working/m-p/292562#M17849 ]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Dropbox has a change in team member file access.
Changing the header **Dropbox-API-Select-User** to **Dropbox-API-Select-Admin** fixed the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#teams-member-file-access